# maxFeePerGas, is this per gas unit? or per the gas the tx needs?

Tags: gas, gas-price, maxfeepergas

Let's say I have a tx that requires **10,000** gas **units**.

Let's say I want to pay upto 50gwei per gas **unit**.

When I send `maxFeePerGas`, do I set it to:

1. `50 * 10^-9` ? // i.e. 50gwei, as in "this is the max price I'm willing to pay per *unit* of gas", or
2. `50 * 10^-9 * 10,000` // i.e. 10,000 * 50gwei as in "this is the max amount I am willing to pay for this tx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the `maxFeePerGas` parameter, you should choose **option 1** i.e., `50 * 10^-9`, which represents **50 gwei**. This parameter indicates the maximum price you're willing to pay per *unit of gas* for the transaction.

The `maxPriorityFeePerGas` parameter is used to specify an additional fee that is paid on top of `maxFeePerGas` in order to prioritise the transaction's inclusion in a block.

However, in your scenario, you only mentioned `maxFeePerGas`, so you would set that to `50 * 10^-9`, indicating your willingness to pay up to **50 gwei** per **gas unit**.